# How to compute for one property in an entity class during Select?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

My table `Persons` has a date of birth column named `DOB`.

In my dbml file, I have added an additional `single` property named `Age`.

In a Linq query, how do I return in `Age` the age calculated from today ad `DOB`?  That is, how do I achieve something like the ficticious code below:

```
 DataClasses1 db = new DataClasses1();
 var pp = from p in db.Persons
       select new Person()
                   {  
                      Name = p.Name, // ... clone all the other properties ...
                      Age = (DateTime.Today-p.DOB).Days/365
                   }
```

Is there another method of achieving the same objective?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put age calculation logic into `Age` property and download only date of birth from database:

```
public int Age 
{
   get { 
      DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
      int age = today.Year - DOB.Year;
      if (DOB > today.AddYears(-age)) age--;
      return age;
   }
}
```

If you want to calculate age on server side (according to tags of question, this is a LINQ to SQL code):

```
from p in db.Persons
let age = SqlMethods.DateDiffYear(p.DOB, DateTime.Today)
select new Person {  
    Name = p.Name,
    Age = SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-age), p.DOB) > 0 ? 
              age - 1 : age
}
```